# Llamar procedimiento de almacenado que lleva fechas PHP y SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

tengo un formulario que tiene dos input tipo date para indicar un periodo de sumatoria para mi procedimiento de almacenado.

Edit: Regrese al código inicial, ya que hice un espagueti que ni yo entendía.

```php
<?php
include("includes/pos_connect.php");

$fechaDesde ="";
$fechaHasta = "";
if(isset($_POST['procesar'])){
  $fechaDesde = $_POST['fechaDesde'];
  $fechaHasta = $_POST['fechaHasta'];
  $query ="{call [dbo].[mostrar_ventas_total] (@fechaDesde={$fechaDesde}, @fechaHasta={$fechaHasta})}";
$resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
if ($resultado === false){
    echo('Algo salió mal: ');
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
    die();
} 
print_r($resultado);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, 2)){
  echo $row['Ventas'];
}
}
?>
```

El SP esta así:

```
@fechaDesde datetime,
@fechaHasta datetime
as
SELECT SUM(precioProducto) as Ventas from ventas
where fecha_de_venta BETWEEN @fechaDesde and @fechaHasta
```

Y actualmente tengo este resultado en mi página:

Resource id #9

Comment: Supongo que las fechas deberían ir entre comillas simples.

Comment: Me parece que para las columnas de tipo `date` o `datetime` SQL Server trabaja con objetos. Intenta crear dos objetos `DateTime` en PHP y pasar esos objetos. Si no sabes cómo crearlos dinos en qué formato vienen las fechas para ayudarte al respecto. Por otra parte, me parece que tienes un *typo* en tu segundo parámetro: `@fechaHasta,$fechaHasta` deberías cambiar la coma por `=`.

Comment: Gracias por responder @A.Cedano , tienes razon con las columnas tipo datetime, modifiqué un poco mi archivo php y ya edite el post para revisar cómo esta hasta el momento mi codigo, espero puedas ayudarme a resolver el error.  El codigo esta un poco sucio, ya que he hecho varias cosas que no me han funcionado pero que me dan errores que podrían ayudarme a resolverlo, por eso no lo he limpiado. El tipo de base de datos que manejo es mssql.

Comment: Te está diciendo _en perfecto castellano_ `Invalid object name 'Ventas'. Seguro del nombre de la tabla?

Comment: Me parece que no puedes darle como alias a la columna el mismo nombre de la tabla (`Ventas` tabla y `Ventas` columna ¿?). Luego, no sé por qué te liaste tanto cambiando las cosas. No hay ningún problema en usar un SP si es lo que necesitas. Ahora tu código me confunde, pues declaras parámetros de entrada (como si quisieras seguir con la SP), pero luego usas una query normal. Clarifica un poco eso y nos dices. Es un problema simple, no hay por qué complicarse tanto: o una cosa (SP) o la otra (query directa). Te ayudará a ti a clarificarte y a nosotros a ayudarte mejor en lo que sea preciso.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, decidí volver al estado original del código para mantener bien claro todo. Opté por quedarme con el SP para también tener menos desorden.